# Как объяснить, когда употребляется *у меня*, а когда *у меня ЕСТЬ*?

Tags: обучение, стилистика, семантика, недопустимая-метка, общие-вопросы

Столкнулась с тем, что не знаю, как объяснить иностранцу в каких случаях, когда мы говорим, что у кого-то что-то есть (например, "у меня есть..."), это "есть" можно (и даже желательно) опустить?
Например:
 1. У меня проблемы (звучит лучше без "есть")
 2. У меня хорошее настроение (без "есть")
 3. У меня есть образование (без "есть" тоже можно сказать, но как-то по-другому звучит)
 4. У меня высшее образование (хочется употребить без "есть").
 5. У меня есть машина.
 6. У меня красивая машина.
 Помогите разобраться!!! спасибо)

Comment: Скорее всего, такие смысловые тонкости рационально объяснить иностранцу практически невозможно. Слишком много трудноуловимых оттенков в понимании. Только многолетняя практика с повседневным языковым общением поможет разобраться с глаголом быть в настоящем времени. Как-то так.

Но конкретный пример поясню. *У меня есть машина* - человек сообщает неизвестный дотоле факт своему визави. *У меня красивая машина* - здесь упор на *красивая*, о существовании машины уже было известно заранее. Все примеры разбирать не буду, места не хватит)))

Answer (score 7):

Интересный вопрос. Попробую на него ответить на основании своего понимания.

- Для того чтобы "быть" что-то в русском языке должно сопровождать более-менее постоянно, а не временно. Поэтому у меня есть нос, руки, ноги, одежда, машина, образование, а преходящие настроения, болезни, проблемы - употребляются без глагола.
- Если чему-то даётся определение, то независимо от того насколько это что-либо постоянно, "есть" опускается. *У меня большой нос, длинные руки и ноги, красивые одежда и машина, при этом ещё и настроение хорошее*. Исключением будут случаи, когда подчёркивается не качества предмета, а именно его наличие.
  *-У тебя есть машина?

  -У меня есть красная машина.*

Comment: мне понравилось ваше объяснение, начала продумывать дальше ряд более-менее постоянных вещей, чтобы употребить их со словом "есть" и поняла, что сюда же попали и "деньги" - пожалуй, самая преходящая вещь в нашем мире )). Без слова "есть" фраза "у меня есть деньги" будет иметь совсем другой смысловой оттенок.

Comment: @trapezzia, всё временно. Любая вещь, а деньги это тоже лишь вещь, рано или поздно исчезнет или станет не моей, но это уже зависит только от меня. А вот настроение, болезнь и проблема от моей воли не зависят. Скорей дело даже в этом.

Answer (score 1):

Есть почти всегда опускается, когда это вспомогательный глагол (to be - в английском) и обычно сохраняется, когда это глагол смысловой ("At me has") так обычно объясняют англоязычным англоязычные преподаватели русского.
Все Ваши примеры вполне подходят под это правило.

<<1. У меня проблемы (звучит лучше без "есть")>>  - нет, лучше как раз с "есть".

Аналогично во всех примерах, кроме втрого.

Comment: У  меня  проблемы.  У  меня  есть  проблемы.  Почему  лучше  с "есть" ?  Фразы  отличаются  смысловыми  нюансами.